DefineStaticWebAssetEndpoints erro in .NET 9 Blazor
I recently updated the .NET version and the VS version to 9.0 and I'm getting this error:

The "DefineStaticWebAssetEndpoints" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable1 source, Func2 keySelector, Func2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer1 comparer)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticWebAssets.Tasks.DefineStaticWebAssetEndpoints.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26. MoveNext()

I tried these steps:

Looked for multiple entries that refer to the same file in .csproj
Clean the build, cache and ran the project again.
Restarted Visual Studio

I am new to .NET and looking for an answer for this issue.

This issue hasn't been totally solved in .net9 preview https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/56029

Thats correct. I downgraded into .net8 and it solved the issue for now. Maybe this will be fixed in a future update.

This error also appears when you generate assets during build. Please show us your project file for analyzing possible culprits.

There is update recently. This issue exist in .NET9.0.100-preview.7. But a release candidate verison .NET9.0.100-rc.1 has just release at Sep 10th. You could try the latest version and this issue has disappeared.

The build result :

